# Limited Folder list using PHP

Tags: php, subdirectory, directory-listing, file-listing

I have multiple sub folders in a folder. I need to show minimum 5 sub folder (Last Updated). Is it possible with PHP?

Comment: We need more details to answer this. Are you having problems showing folders at all? Do you need help limiting the iterations of a loop to 5?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow!. [Read FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to help you interact with this Q/A site.

Now, let's move to the question. If I understand your question correctly (which is quite hard, given the sparse information you gave to us), you want to display 5 subfolder from certain folder.

It's quite simple, you can use a combination of [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php), and [krsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) for that. Here's the example:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: Text/Plain');
$dir = "d:/";

$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
$filenames = array();
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ( !$fileinfo->isFile() ) {
        $filenames[$fileinfo->getMTime()] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    }
}

print_r($filenames);

krsort($filenames);

print_r($filenames);

$maxDisplay = count( $filenames ) < 5 ? count( $filenames ) : 5;

$count=0;
foreach( $filenames  as $timestamp => $filename ) {
    $count++;
    echo "{$count}. {$filename}\n";
    if( $count == $maxDisplay) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `exec("ls"...)` or `glob(...)`?

Comment: I don't really understand `glob()`. `exec()` will limit the solution to only linux system. However, you might want to try to answer this question using `glob()`. You know, so we have another alternative.

Comment: @saravana good!. Don't forget to vote up and mark as the right answer